# The username used for a failed login attempt is not reported anymore

Tags: authentication-authorization, 10, log-messages

Just completed a migration of a site from Drupal 7 to 10, and it's gone pretty smoothly after quite a bit of preparation.
One thing seems different in a frustrating way: In the prior site on Drupal7, failed login attempts would be logged as eg "Login attempt failed for admin." or "Login attempt failed for [mis-spelled name]".

Once upgraded, it appears that failed attempts only list a username if that username exists (and there is no user called admin), otherwise these just log an ip address.
Am I correct in interpreting this, and is there a simple way to replicate the old behaviour?
To be clear, I find it useful to be able to display the username: my clients use this day-to-day supporting users who are getting usernames wrong.

I'll probably find a relevant hook if there's no existing solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct to say that the username is logged only when there is an account matching that username. That is what [`UserLoginForm::validateFinal()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserLoginForm.php/function/UserLoginForm%3A%3AvalidateFinal/10) does.

```php
// Use $form_state->getUserInput() in the error message to guarantee
// that we send exactly what the user typed in. The value from
// $form_state->getValue() may have been modified by validation
// handlers that ran earlier than this one.
$user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
$query = isset($user_input['name']) ? ['name' => $user_input['name']] : [];
$form_state->setErrorByName('name', $this->t('Unrecognized username or password. <a href=":password">Forgot your password?</a>', [':password' => Url::fromRoute('user.pass', [], ['query' => $query])->toString()]));
$accounts = $this->userStorage->loadByProperties(['name' => $form_state->getValue('name')]);
if (!empty($accounts)) {
  $this->logger('user')
    ->notice('Login attempt failed for %user.', ['%user' => $form_state->getValue('name')]);
}
else {
  // If the username entered is not a valid user,
  // only store the IP address.
  $this->logger('user')
    ->notice('Login attempt failed from %ip.', ['%ip' => $this->getRequest()->getClientIp()]);
}
```

To log what has been entered in the login form as username, you can add a validation handler that contains code similar to the following one.

```php
if (!$form_state->get('uid')) {
  // The login attempt failed.
  $user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
  $ip = Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
  \Drupal::logger('mymodule')->notice('Login attempt failed (user: "%user", IP: %ip).', ['%user' => $user_input['name'] ?? '', '%ip' => $ip]);
}
```

I used `$form_state->getUserInput()` for the same reason given in the `UserLoginForm::validateFinal()` comment: `$form_state->getUserInput()` returns exactly what has been entered in the form, while the value returned by `$form_state->getValue()` could have been modified by any validation handler.

Comment: That looks fantastic thanks.